# Why doesn't this media query hit retina?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm struggling with a media query trying to target retina screens.
I got this media query;

```
@media(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ration:2)and (min-resolution:192dpi) {}
```

In Chrome Canary Devtools it does get the style but testing it on a actually retina display (iphone 5s in this case) does not.

I also use this viewport so it scales everything, I tried to remove it but it didn't do any difference in my issue above.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=0.5 maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

Any ideas on why I have this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this media query, it works

```
@media  
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),  
only screen and ( min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),  
only screen and ( -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),  
only screen and ( min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),  
only screen and ( min-resolution: 192dpi),  
only screen and ( min-resolution: 2dppx){
   //your css goes here..
}
```

Also change the viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Thanks. My media query works also. Missed that it said `-ration:` (face palm). This was a more extensive media query.

Comment: It happens Sometimes :)